# Causative verbs: Can we say "She went into the kitchen to have got dinner ready"?

Tags: infinitives

Can we use 'have got something done/adjective'. I understand this sentence: 'She went to the kitchen to get dinner ready'. But 'to have got dinner ready' seems strange for me.

Comment: I see you're using single quotation marks, which is indicative of British English, so is your use of 'got'. In British English, there is no word 'gotten'. 'Gotten' is an Americanism. Brits say 'got' where Yanks say 'gotten'. So answerers to this question should be versed in British English, or, ideally, be actual Brits.

Comment: The title of your question asks about causative verbs. A version of your sentence using "_have_" causatively moves "_got_" one place to the right: _She went into the kitchen to have dinner got ready_. This is feasible if she is the manager of a hotel and wants her chefs to start preparing dinner.

Answer (score 3):

No, we can't say that, because it would mean "She went into the kitchen in order to have [already] prepared dinner", which makes no sense.

However, we could say "She was glad to have got her work done early, because it meant that she had plenty of time to get ready to go out." (This is speaking of her thoughts *after* doing the work.)

Comment: Or *she* could say ***I want / intend / plan / hope** to have got dinner ready by 6 o'clock [so I can watch TV for an hour before we eat at 7]*. That's still speaking of her thoughts ***before*** doing the work.